# How Do I Pull The Application Version Listed in AndroidManifest.xml From Java?

Tags: android

How Do I Pull The Application Version Listed in AndroidManifest.xml From Java, `android:versionName` specifically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`PackageInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#versionName) class. Something along the lines of:

```
PackageInfo myInfo;
myInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0)
version = myInfo.versionName;
```

`getPackageName()` returns the full name of your package (the one that called it). If you were looking to find version information on a different package, you might want to wrap this in a `try {...} catch` block, in case the package you were looking for wasn't installed. There's an example of that [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/about-me-packageinfoversionname-and.html).